# Entity Framework 6 with Mysql and NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I try to insert same data I am getting NullReferenceException exception.

I have read tons of posts in Stackoverflow, asp.net forums and mysql community forums. 
I could not found any true solution for this problem. There is a lots of answer about that. However anyone solved my problem (also another people's problems). I found some bug reports about problem like that. However every reports should solved in .Net Connector 6.8.3.
I think I am missing very simple step in EF with Mysql but I could not found what is my mistakes...

Sample Code:

```
using (prodEntities myEntity = new prodEntities ())
{
  userloginlog log = new userloginlog();
  log.UserRef = pUserID;
  log.Success = pSuccess;
  log.IpNo = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
  log.BrowserInfo = browserInfo;
  log.LoginTime = GeneralHelperC.getCompanyDateTime();
  myEntity.userloginlog.Add(log);
  myEntity.SaveChanges();
}
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `userloginlog` (
  `RID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserRef` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `LoginTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `IpNo` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Success` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `BrowserInfo` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RID`),
  KEY `userLoginLog_Staff_Key` (`UserRef`),
  CONSTRAINT `UserLoginLog_User_Key` FOREIGN KEY (`UserRef`) REFERENCES `users` (`RID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16903 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Exception:

```
   at MySql.Data.Entity.ListFragment.WriteSql(StringBuilder sql)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.WriteSql(StringBuilder sql)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.InsertStatement.WriteSql(StringBuilder sql)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlFragment.ToString()
   at MySql.Data.Entity.InsertGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(Dictionary`2 identifierValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__d()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClassb.<SaveChangesInternal>b__8()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Installed in my computer:

- Mysql Server 5.6CE
- MySQL Connector NET 6.8.3
- Visual Studio 2013

Refenced DLL's in project (everyone installed with nuget):

- MySql.Data.dll (6.8.3)
- MySql.Data.Entity.dll (6.7.5)
- MySql.Data.Entities.dll (6.8.3.0)
- MySql.Web.dll (6.8.3)
- EntityFramework.dll (6.1.1)

Project is Asp.Net Webform which running under .Net Framework 4.0

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you post the entity class?

Comment: It has been 9 months since you've posted, have you ever found out the root cause and workaround? I get exactly the same error myself

Comment: Também estou com o mesmo erro!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Entity Framework 6, the correct MySql Data Entity to use is `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6`. I have a Webforms project and I am using VS 2013 with MySql. The Mysql references look like this:

[image]

You don't need your `MySql.Data.Entity.dll (6.7.5)` or `MySql.Data.Entities.dll (6.8.3.0)`.

For your Web.config:

```
 <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
                type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
           invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
           type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data,  Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Comment: Actually I have two project. One of web other is Entity model project. Entity model project is referenced from Web project. After your answer I tried to create new Model in Web Project but I had got that error: 
"Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. Exit this wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuid your project before performing this action"
After that error I have some search but again any answer solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue. We didn't have an ID field, but we had a timestamp as primary key. The solution was to introduce an ID, and set that to be the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

As I took a closer look, EF was considering all fields in the table in question as keys. Unfortunately I was short on time so rather than investigating, I recreated the table from scratch, deleted entity types from the model and re-imported them from the database.

After that the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had been having the same issue as Balaz Somogyi, which is similar to OP's (I am referencing version 6.9.7 of both MySQL.Data and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6). I had a log table with a `TimeStamp` field as the primary key. When Entity Framework generated the `.edmx` it set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property on the primary key field set to `Identity`. Since I was not relying on Entity Framework to return the inserted `TimeStamp` I opted to set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property to `None` rather than changing the table structure in the database. This resolved the issue for me.